# hazelcast map is not ready warnings

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am trying hazelcast v3.3 - I keep seeing the following (same as v3.2).  I am guessing I might be doing something wrong but it seems like its tied to when the loadAll gets called for mapstore implementations.  I am running hazelcast server on ubuntu v13 and am assigning 2GB RAM (small cluster of 4VMs).  Any thoughts what might be causing this (config or implementation) - this simply has not gone away for me (and the client cannot seem to get data at this point since the map is not ready).  I am using async backup and not synchronous backup for the map entries.

```
2014-09-14 18:56:09,429 WARN c.h.s.i.BasicInvocation [hz._hzInstance_1_testApp.partition-operation.thread-0] [192.168.110.159]:5701 [testApp] [3.3] Retrying invocation: BasicInvocation{ servi
ceName='hz:impl:mapService', op=com.hazelcast.map.operation.MapSizeOperation@7969fd40, partitionId=4, replicaIndex=0, tryCount=250, tryPauseMillis=500, invokeCount=100, callTimeout=60000, target=Ad
dress[192.168.110.159]:5701}, Reason: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.RetryableHazelcastException: Map is not ready!!!
```

**Update:**
It does not seem like its GC related - I am running a pretty small node (roughly 100MB) on a single node.  I see this call periodically and the client cannot seem to get any information from the server when this happens!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly this is not really an issue; the exception is logged on warning but it is something to be expected.

Hazelcast relies on certain types of exceptions for control flow (I know. in most applications this would be bad). In this case an exception is thrown when the map is still loading that indicates to the invoker; please try a bit later again because currently I'm not ready. The invoker will do a back-off and tries again a bit later until either a timeout happens or until the loading phase completes and the operation is executed successfully.

I guess what happens is that the exception is logged under warning; but it should be logged under debug.

Comment: thank you - I will check my logic again - I load the maps at startup time but I have seen this on the client after hours later.  I have to dig more to find out why

Answer (score 0):

Check your memory/heap settings and see if GC is taking place at the same time as these "Map is not ready" calls.  Most likely it is.  Try different variations (G1GC, if not G1GC, try different size ratios for new and old generation and try to figure out where the GC is taking longer and try to configure that the best you can).  I would suggest looking at the network logs as well depending on how many nodes you're running this on.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your Map is lazy loading and what you really want is for it to eager load. Hazelcast added a flag that can be set to require eager load. ...

```
MapStoreConfig.InitialMode=EAGER
```

This fixes Hazelcast issue [1593 -- Map is not ready!!! exception](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/1593). Also see issue [1707 -- Initial Load Types](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/1707).

Comment: thank you - I marked the map as EAGER and call up the maps at start up time in any case to ensure thay the map store implementation gets called up.  Sometimes, even though the map appears to have been loaded, the client gets this response that map is not ready